# F# list to Vectors MathNet.Numerics

Tags: list, vector, f#

I am trying to churn out a list of randoms and turn it into a vector using MathNet.Numerics. But my F# Interactive returns(below) instead of the values generated. Below is my code.

> val cumRC : DenseVector

would expect to return something like this.

```
cumRC : float list =
  [0.9888577146; 1.013791155; 0.9816407702; 0.9967110693; 1.000800844;
   1.004584863; 0.999112488; 0.9908830826; 1.009421593; 1.00276232]
```

```
open MathNet.Numerics
open MathNet.Numerics.Distributions
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Generic.FSharpExtensions

let genRandom count =
    let rnd = Normal(0.0,1.0)

    List.init count (fun _ -> 1.0 + rnd.Sample()/100.0)

let va = genRandom 10

let cumVa =  List.scan (fun numbers n -> numbers * n) 1.0 va |> List.tail |> DenseVector.ofList
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used MathNet but removing the parts that are specific to that package produces the expected results.  So the code with the MathNet parts stripped out is:

```
let rnd = new System.Random()
let genRandom count =   
    List.init count (fun _ ->  rnd.Next())

let va = genRandom 10

let cumVa =  List.scan (fun numbers n -> numbers * n) 1 va |> List.tail
```

Which produces:

```
 val cumVa : int list =
  [893568767; -84811745; 1485049601; -1376682691; -278974486; -902716576;
   -1616974272; 1049846592; -1969542592; -2077634944]
```

So most likely place to look is the documentation for DenseVector. A quick google says that it doesn't have an ofList function.

Comment: There is a ofList function. From here. [link](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/FSharpExamples/Vectors.fsx)  I try using matrix and it works, just not vectors.